# Running Zoom slows down network speed considerably

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, download-speed, zoom-meeting

My Speedtest results are typically ~100mbs download and upload. However, every time I run Zoom meetings, the video and audio break/lag and I'm warned with the "Your Internet Connection is Unstable" popup.

While running Zoom, using speedtest services shows around 0.1mbs download/upload.

After killing Zoom (sigterm) using speedtest services show around 0.1mbs download/upload.

Only after both killing zoom, and restarting the `network-manager` service does the network return to ~100mbs results.

Clearly, Zoom is causing some weird network artifacts to come up on Ubuntu, as even after it's quit the impact it has on my normal browsing remains. Does anyone have any idea on what might be going on and how I can fix this???

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing!